# Headers aren't being sent in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code:

```
$service_url = 'https://api.familysearch.org/reservation/v1/person/L6GD-YYV';

$curl = curl_init($service_url);
$headr = array();
$headr[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$headr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$headr[] = 'Authorization: OAuth '.$_SESSION['fs-session'];

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

$curl_res = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($curl_res);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($curl_res);
var_dump($response);
```

When I try to retrieve the resource it gives me a 401 Unauthorized even though I am supplying an access token. I then took a look at the headers being sent and found that none of the headers that I set through this code (the access token header) are being sent. Is there something wrong with my code that is preventing the headers from being sent?

Comment: Try with `$headr[] = 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="' . $_SESSION['fs-session'] . '"';`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Accept header and Authorization type:

```
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE
```